# MongoDB: aggregation - group condition if not empty

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

If have data like this:

```
{
 user: "max",
 uploaded: <timestamp>,
 updated: <timestamp>
}
{
 user: "tim",
 uploaded: <timestamp>
}
```

Ever user can have different Items. Now I use the mongoDB aggregation framework with $match + $group like this:

```
aggregate([
{ $match: {"username": "foouser"}},
{ $group: {
  ...other items..
  "last_active": max(updated) OR IF EMPTY max(uploaded)
}
]);
```

I want to set "last_active" to the max timestamp of updated so get the last active of a User over all his items. But not every item has a update-property. Maybe there is on update-property in any element of a user. So if max(updated) is empty he should pick max(uploaded).

Can anyone help me with this condition in a group-order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregation pipeline changed a lot from version to version, so it is recommended that you use the latest stable version of mongodb.

Try to combine $max and $setUnion operators, like this:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
    { $match: {"username": "foouser"}},
    { $group: {
    ...other items..
    "last_active": { $max: { $setUnion: [ "$updated", "$uploaded" ] } }
    }
]);
```

Or $ifNull and $max:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
    { $match: {"username": "foouser"}},
    { $group: {
    ...other items..
    "last_active": { $max: { $ifNull: [ "$updated", "$uploaded" ] } }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you! $setUnion is not supported in my mongo-db version but it works well with $ifNull!